# Peity Sparklines , customizing

Tags: jquery

We are using this excellent plugin for some small sparkline charts.

Issue I have is changing colours of the sparklines, sizes etc. The documentation is very brief.

We are using LINE and BAR charts.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please. Or do a quick snippet with custom colours, and size configurations for the sparkline types we need.

http://benpickles.github.com/peity/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey, have a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/jpz3m/

Basically you can setup the colors when initializing the plugin :

```
$(".line").peity("line",{
    colour: "#FF2200",
    strokeColour:"#882200",
    strokeWidth:2,
  }
);
```

The default options are :

```
$.fn.peity.defaults.pie = {
  colours: ["#FFF4DD", "#FF9900"],
  delimeter: "/",
  radius: 16
};

$.fn.peity.defaults.line = {
  colour: "#c6d9fd",
  strokeColour: "#4d89f9",
  strokeWidth: 1,
  delimeter: ",",
  height: 16,
  max: null,
  width: 32
};

$.fn.peity.defaults.bar = {
  colour: "#4D89F9",
  delimeter: ",",
  height: 16,
  max: null,
  width: 32
};
```

Comment: I'm loving jsfiddle.net, nice tip!

Comment: @RaceFace I discovered it here too :)

Comment: colour should be fill and strokeColour should just be stroke.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you need to use a vanilla js version of peity charts - https://github.com/railsjazz/peity_vanilla